# Plupload multiple instances

Tags: plupload

I'm trying to set up unknown number of plupload instances on page. I need to dynamically add more instances and remove and reset some of them. I have the general idea, but nothing works.

One of my tries is on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gzuri/X65zF/).

Thank you for all the help.

Code:

```
var uploaders = new Array();

initUploaders = function(uploaders) {
    console.log("initUploaders()");
    $(".gallery").each(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        var button = el.attr("id") + "_uploader";
        console.log("Init uploader id:" + el.attr("id"));
        var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
            runtimes: 'gears,html5,flash,silverlight,browserplus',
            browse_button: button,
            max_file_size: '10mb',
            url: 'ModuleGallery/Upload/',
            flash_swf_url: 'http://static.srv42.net/plupload/js/plupload.flash.swf',
            silverlight_xap_url: 'http://static.srv42.net/plupload/js/plupload.silverlight.xap',
            filters: [
                {
                title: "Image files",
                extensions: "jpg,gif,png"}
            ]
        });        

        uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
            uploader.start();
        });

        uploader.init();    
        galleryUploaders.push(uploader);
    };

    initUploaders(uploaders);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63463460/5049864

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer was pretty simple in the end. You can instance it normally and just bind to QueueChanged event.

```
uploader.bind('QueueChanged', function (up, files) {
     uploader.start();
     up.refresh();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've fixed up your original jsfiddle and (though of course the file doesn't upload to anywhere) it does seem to attempt it correctly once these extra lines are in place. http://jsfiddle.net/X65zF/36/

Comment: @Gavin This is my new link ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25440360/how-to-use-multiple-instances-of-plupload-on-single-form..suggest me solution..

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution. You can have `n` number of instances with this:

- [Multiple Instances of Plupload](http://jsfiddle.net/X65zF/36/) - jSFiddle